# How to do concatenation in path of mailbee LoadMessage

Tags: c#, email

This is code i used to fetch all names from a folder with their extensions

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\DLogs\Notification11");
foreach (string file in files)
{

    //Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
    listOfFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    mailBeeTask(listOfFiles);
}
```

Now the problem is that in mailBeeTask(listOfFiles) i am giving filename with extension but the mailbee uses

```
mailer.Message.LoadMessage(@"D:\DLogs\Notification11\mailbee.eml");
```

this is mailbee code

```
public static void mailBeeTask(IList<string> ListOfTasks)
{
    //send emails
    Smtp mailer = new Smtp();

    // Use SMTP relay server with authentication.
    mailer.SmtpServers.Add("smtp.domain.com", "joe@domain.com", 
    "secret");

    // Load the message from .EML file (it must be in MIME RFC2822 
    format).
    mailer.Message.LoadMessage(@"D:\DLogs\Notification11\mailbee.eml");
    **//this above line is the problem, how can i use ListOfTasks 
    instead 
    //of mailbee.eml should i concatenate or what??**

    // Demonstrate that we can modify the loaded message.
    // Update the date when the message was composed to the current 
    moment.
    mailer.Message.Date = DateTime.Now;

    mailer.Send();
}
```

Mailbee is used to send emails made by afterlogic.

Comment: What is a "mailbee"? 

Comment: https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net, Its is sending mails service by afterlogics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per logic you want to send all message files in the given directory. Because a single file per se is a single, complete message, you have to send each file/message seperately.

You correctly get all the files. But then you have to execute the `mailBeeTask` for each single file.

So the two lines in the for each would get

```cs
mailBeeTask(file);
```

and the signature of `mailBeeTask` has to change to

```cs
public static void mailBeeTask(string filename)
```

followed by using the parameter in the last change

```cs
mailer.Message.LoadMessage(filename);
```

Your code will now loop through all files in the directory specified and then will call the `mailBeeTask` method with the complete file name as the parameter. The method then loads the single file, modifies the date and sends it.

With the given code in your OP you also will also suffer the following: you first add the file to the `listOfFiles` and then execute the `mailBeeTask` for each file in the list. In the next iteration this causes all prior files in the list again being provided as the parameter. With already working code, you would have sent all prior files and the current files within one iteration.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed. Thumbs Up.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal No problem! Please also don't forget to upvote, thanks! I'm glad I was able to help you!

Comment: Sorry i cant vote up as its saying i need 15+reputation as i am new here. But Really Thanks a lot i will do it later after 15+reputation here.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal do you have sufficient rights now? I just got another upvote and stumbled upon your comment, again :)